# Construct unique arrays from nested array values with common parents

Tags: arrays, json, jq

Likely a close question to [JQ: Nested JSON transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755787/jq-nested-json-transformation) but I wasn't able to get my head around it.

**Sample JSON:**

```
"value": [
{
  "FeatureStatus": [
    {
      "FeatureName": "Sway1",
      "FeatureServiceStatus": "ServiceOperational"
    },
    {
      "FeatureName": "Sway2",
      "FeatureServiceStatus": "ServiceDegraded"
    }
  ],
  "Id": "SwayEnterprise",
},
{
  "FeatureStatus": [
    {
      "FeatureName": "yammerfeatures",
      "FeatureServiceStatus": "ServiceOperational"
    }
  ],
  "Id": "yammer"
}
]
```

What I want to do is create an output with jq which results in the following;

```
{"Sway":"Sway1":"ServiceOperational"},
{"Sway":"Sway2":"ServiceDegraded"},
{"Yammer":"yammerfeatures":"ServiceOperational"}
```

My various attempts either end up with thousands of non-unique (i.e Yammer with Sway status), or only one Id with x number of FeatureServiceStatus.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I've gone through the tutorial and the cookbook. I am perhaps 2.5 days into using jq.

Comment: 1. Please fix the input so that it is as you say, valid JSON. 2. Do you really want invalid JSON as output? 3. Please clarify the relationship between the input and the "Sway" and "Yammer" top-level elements of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the enclosing braces have been added to make the input valid JSON, the filter:

```
.value[]
| [.Id] + (.FeatureStatus[] | [ .FeatureName, .FeatureServiceStatus ])
```

produces:

```
["SwayEnterprise","Sway1","ServiceOperational"]
["SwayEnterprise","Sway2","ServiceDegraded"]
["yammer","yammerfeatures","ServiceOperational"]
```

You can then easily reformat this as desired.

Comment: My bad, but yes, the JSON is valid on my end (just got lazy copy+pasting here). Your solution is perfect, and now that I see it written I understand how jq is constructing it. Thanks :)